# Jquery check two inputs for same value

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to write Jquery code to check if two inputs have the same value on form submit without luck.

If input with id "id1" has the same value as input with id "id2" alert "some text" and return false.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
    var id1 = $(#id1).text();
    var id2 = $(#id2).text();
    if (id1 == id2) {
        alert('Error, cant do that');
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
    return true;
    }

});
```

Comment: Please post the code you have so far. Though I cannot imagine what can go wrong using the comparison operator. It's so simple that I assume there is something else wrong with your code, or the values.

Comment: $('#form').submit(function() {
 var id1 = $(#id1).text();
 var id2 = $(#id2).text();
 if (id1 == id2) {
  alert('Error, can't do that');
  return false;
 }
 else
 {
 return true;
 }
 
});

Comment: There are two things wrong with your code: Selectors must be strings, i.e. `#id1` must be `'#id1'`, and `text()` won't retrieve the value of an input field (why do you think it does?), use `.val()` instead. jQuery's documentation is pretty good and it's the first thing you should read if you are unsure about methods. Simply printing `id1` and `id2` would have been a good start for debugging.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/g2kBm/2/)

```
<input type="text" id="id1" />
<input type="text" id="id2" />

$('input').blur(function() {
if ($('#id1').attr('value') == $('#id2').attr('value')) {
alert('Same Value');
return false;
} else { return true; }
});
```

I simply used blur rather than a form submit.

Answer (score 6):

It's pretty simple, just do a comparison with `==` and the input's values. Place this inside of the `submit()` of your form.

```
var match = $('#id1').val() == $('#id2').val();
```

If `match` is `false`, then you can show your `alert()` and `event.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you have miss type your code, try to replace from `$(#id1)` to `$('#id1')` so as from `$(#id2)` to `$('#id2')`

Corrected code

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
    var id1 = $('#id1').text(); //if #id1 is input element change from .text() to .val() 
    var id2 = $('#id2').text(); //if #id2 is input element change from .text() to .val()
    if (id1 == id2) {
        alert('Error, cant do that');
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: If `#idX` are input elements, then `.text()` won't return their values.

Comment: @FelixKling you are right, if `#idX` are input elements then to retrieve value need to change form `.text()` to `.attr('value')` or just `.val()`